# How to allow user to log in with another user account via facebook when using InAppBrowser-reborn in react native app

Tags: react-native, inappbrowser

I'm using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn package to open signIn with facebook page, when I try to Signin, automatically logged in to previous account.I'm not able to choose an account.I think this happens due to previous session that stored inside InAppbrowser. I can`t find a way to clear them from app side. Is there any solution to prevent using previous session cookies??
Need a solution to work in both ios and android.